# How to get the value of the textbox that has keyboard focus?

Tags: python, winapi, ctypes, pywin32

I want to retrieve the value of the textbox in which the user is typing into

So far, I've got this code that outputs what's written in the element of which I have my keyboard focus.
However, it only works for the text area of the Notepad, and when I try to use it on other apps, it prints things like "Chrome Legacy Window"

```
from ctypes import windll, create_unicode_buffer
import win32gui
import win32con
import time

def getForegroundWindowTitle():
    hWnd = windll.user32.GetForegroundWindow()
    length = windll.user32.GetWindowTextLengthW(hWnd)
    buf = create_unicode_buffer(length + 1)
    windll.user32.GetWindowTextW(hWnd, buf, length + 1)
    
    if buf.value:
        return buf.value
    else:
        return None

time.sleep(3)
windowHandle = win32gui.FindWindow(None, getForegroundWindowTitle())
childwindowHandle = win32gui.FindWindowEx(windowHandle, None, win32gui.GetFocus(), None)
buff = create_unicode_buffer(4096)
win32gui.SendMessage(childwindowHandle, win32con.WM_GETTEXT, 4096, buff) #0x000D
print(buff.value)
```

Comment: Use UI Automation for that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-understandingtheuiautomationtextobjectmodel with python, I guess you can use this:

Comment: I forgot the link https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto

Comment: I managed to get a textbox's value with pywinauto
```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time
app = Application(backend="uia").start('notepad.exe')

time.sleep(3)
print(app["*Sans titre\xa0- Bloc-notes"]["EDIT"].get_value())
```
but I still need to specify the element ("Edit")

Comment: use the Inspect tool from the Windows SDK to check the UI Automation tree and the UIA patterns each element support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [IUIAutomation::GetFocusedElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation-getfocusedelement) retrieves the current UI Automation element that has the input focus, and then get the Value Pattern.

Here is a win32 sample in C++, you could feel free to convert it in Python:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <UIAutomation.h>
BOOL main()
{
    HRESULT hr;
    CoInitialize(0);
    Sleep(2000);
    IUIAutomation* pClientUIA;
    hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_CUIAutomation, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IUIAutomation, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&pClientUIA));
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("CoCreateInstance error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    IUIAutomationElement* pFocusedElement;
    hr = pClientUIA->GetFocusedElement(&pFocusedElement);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("GetFocusedElement error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    IValueProvider* pValueProvider;
    hr = pFocusedElement->GetCurrentPattern(UIA_ValuePatternId, reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**> (&pValueProvider));
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("GetCurrentPattern error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }

    BSTR text;
    hr = pValueProvider->get_Value(&text);
    if (S_OK != hr)
    {
        printf("get_Value error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return FALSE;
    }
    wprintf(L"%s\n", text);
    SysFreeString(text);

    CoUninitialize();
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Does your code work everywhere? I made it in C# (python seemed too limited), but it only works in a few text boxes (everywhere on Edge, in the Chrome search bar and that's all)

Comment: It does not support all types of controls. The [control type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-controltype-ids) which supports `IValueProvider` could work, like [UIA_EditControlTypeId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supporteditcontroltype#required-control-patterns), [UIA_DocumentControlTypeId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-supportdocumentcontroltype#required-control-patterns)

Comment: You could use [inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) to check the control type.

Comment: You may need to write different methods for different types of controls. BTW, which text boxes you cannot get the value?

Comment: I added a code to support DocumentControlType. It now works on Notepad, Word, etc, but it still doesn't work for every app (not everywhere on Chrome, not on Discord); neither the TextPattern nor ValuePattern are available, even though their control type is Document and the Microsoft doc says it must support the ITextProvider interface.

Comment: Sorry for missing, you also need to use [GetCurrentPropertyValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nf-uiautomationclient-iuiautomationelement-getcurrentpropertyvalue) to check [Control Pattern Availability Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/uiauto-control-pattern-availability-propids)

Comment: I'm already using `(bool) automation_Element.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.IsTextPatternAvailableProperty) == true` before getting the text - problem is it returns False, even though it should be True according to the Microsoft Doc because it's a Document Control Type

Comment: It seems that you are **not** able to write unified code for "textbox" everywhere, you need to write for a specific control or a specific type of control. You can use inspect.exe to check the available properties of the control. Could you share the control you're using?

Comment: The problem may be coming from `AutomationElement.FocusedElement`. The focused element returned by `AutomationElement.FocusedElement` is different from the one said to be focused by inspect.exe (which is the correct one). `AutomationElement.FocusedElement.GetCurrentPropertyValue(AutomationElement.HasKeyboardFocusProperty)` also says the FocusedElement is not focused; it happens on VS Code and Discord.

Comment: I've tried to use `automation_Element.FindAll(TreeScope.Descendants, new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Edit))` in order to get the correct element, but it didn't work (the elements returned are the same as `automation_Element`, and it's also very slow)

Comment: Do you really focus on the element? I can get the content entered in the edit control with VS code app.

Comment: I couldn't fix the issue with `AutomationElement.FocusedElement` not working properly, so I finally did it in C++ as you implied. Thank you for your help!